# How to store dynamic bytes in memory in solidity inline assembly?

Tags: solidity, uniswapv2

this is my code to test transferring some tokens to the target address, which functions well.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

import "./interface/IERC20.sol";
import "./lib/SafeTransfer.sol";

contract Mycontract {

    // transfer(address,uint256)
    bytes4 internal constant TRANSFER = 0xa9059cbb;
    // swap(uint256,uint256,address,bytes)
    bytes4 internal constant PAIR_SWAP = 0x022c0d9f;

    // Contructor sets the only user
    receive() external payable {}

    fallback() external payable {
        assembly {
          
                let token := shr(96, calldataload(0x00))
            
                let addr := shr(96, calldataload(0x14))
                
                let amount := shr(128, calldataload(0x28))

                mstore(0x00, TRANSFER) 
                mstore(0x04, addr)
                mstore(0x24, amount)
                
                let s := call(sub(gas(), 5000), token, 0, 0x00, 0x44, 0, 0)
            }
            
    }
            
}
```

As you can see at https://ethervm.io/#F1, the parameters of the call are "gas|addr|argsOffset   |argsLength|retOffset|retLength". In this case, 0x00 is the starting memory location of parameters of the transfer method, including 4bytes function signature and all parameters. 0x44 is the length of the parameters, 0x04(function signature) + 0x20(address) + 0x20(uint256), right?

However, if the method has a parameter of dynamic bytes, how to store it in memory and set the length? For example, I want to call Uniswap v2 pair's swap function:

```
 function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data)
```

This is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

import "./interface/IERC20.sol";
import "./lib/SafeTransfer.sol";

contract Mycontract {

    // transfer(address,uint256)
    bytes4 internal constant TRANSFER = 0xa9059cbb;
    // swap(uint256,uint256,address,bytes)
    bytes4 internal constant PAIR_SWAP = 0x022c0d9f;

    // Contructor sets the only user
    receive() external payable {}

    fallback() external payable {
        assembly {

            let pair := shr(96, calldataload(0x00))
        
            let tokenAmountOut := calldataload(0x14)
            
            mstore(0x00, PAIR_SWAP)
            mstore(0x04, tokenAmountOut)
            mstore(0x24, 0)
            mstore(0x44, address())
            mstore(0x64, ???)  // I want the length of this is zer0, what value shoud it be?
            
            let s := call(sub(gas(), 5000), pair, 0, 0x00, ???, 0, 0) // what the length should be?
            
        }       
    }        
}
```

How to set empty bytes in memory and how to calculate the length of the parameters?